# Implement a reset feature in Kivy App

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Below is a little Kivy app I'm working on.  At the moment I'm trying to implement a basic reset feature.  Essentially, if an enemy collides with the player, I want the game to reset.  The games ends by unscheduling clock schedules upon collision with an enemy.  I thought after that I could just call main() afterwards, but this simply causes massive bugs where the game spews out errors left and right.  I also tried added reschedule rules after the unshedule, but that just overrides the unshedule and keeps the game going.

**Note**: The game is handled mostly from the game class towards the bottom of the code.  It's also where you'll see clock schedule rules.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import math
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
import random

sound = SoundLoader.load('gamemusic.mp3')
PLAYER_SPEED = 10
ENEMY_SPEED = 4
ENEMY_SPAWN = 5
UPDATE_SPEED = .01
MIN_INITIAL_PLAYER_MINION_DISTANCE = 200
UPDATE_SCORE = 1
MAX_DECOYS = 3


if sound:
    sound.loop = True
    sound.play()


class Movable(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    target = ListProperty([])
    def move(self):

        dx = self.target[0] - self.center[0]
        dy = self.target[1] - self.center[1]
        total = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
        if total >0:
            self.velocity_x = (dx / total) * self.speed
            self.velocity_y = (dy / total) * self.speed
            new_x = self.pos[0] + self.velocity_x
            new_y = self.pos[1] + self.velocity_y
            self.pos = (new_x,new_y)
        elif total <=0:
            self.velocity_x = self.speed
            self.velocity_y = self.speed


class Player(Movable):
    target = ListProperty([])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.target = [399.0, 399.0]
        self.speed = PLAYER_SPEED
    def update_target(self, new_target):
        self.target = new_target
        if distance_pos(self.center, self.target) <= self.speed*2:
            self.target = self.center

class Enemy(Movable):
    randomColor = random.randint(0,1)
    alert = BooleanProperty(False)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.world_width =  kwargs.get("width",0)
        self.world_height = kwargs.get("height",0)
        self.speed = ENEMY_SPEED
        x_target = float(random.randint(0, self.world_width))
        y_target = float(random.randint(0, self.world_height))

        self.target = [x_target, y_target]
        self.center = kwargs.get('start_pos',[0,0])
    def update_target(self, player, enemies, decoys):
        alert_list = self.alerted(enemies)
        if len(decoys) > 0:
            self.target = decoys[0].center
            self.alert = False
        elif distance(player, self) < 150:
            self.alert = True
            self.target = player.center
        elif len(alert_list) > 0:
            self.target = alert_list[0].center
            self.alert = False
        else:
            if distance_pos(self.center, self.target) <= self.speed*2:
                x_new_target = float(random.randint(0, self.world_width))
                y_new_target = float(random.randint(0, self.world_height))
                self.target = [x_new_target, y_new_target]
    def alerted(self, enemies):
        alert_list = []
        for item in enemies:
            if item.alert == True and distance(self, item) < 150:
                alert_list.append(item)
        return alert_list
class Decoy(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.center = kwargs.get('start_pos',[0,0])
    pass

def distance(widget1, widget2):
    return distance_pos(widget1.center, widget2.center)
def distance_pos(pos1, pos2):
    dist = math.sqrt((pos1[0]-pos2[0])**2 + (pos1[1]-pos2[1])**2)
    return dist

class Game(Widget):
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    enemies = ListProperty([])
    decoys = ListProperty([])
    score = NumericProperty()

    def setup(self):
        self.enemies = []
        self.decoys = []
        self.player1.center = self.center
        self.setup_schedules()
    #Don't forget about good code organization!
    def setup_schedules(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, UPDATE_SPEED)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.spawn_enemy, ENEMY_SPAWN)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increase_score, UPDATE_SCORE)



    def update(self,dt):
        self.player1.move()
        for item in self.enemies:
            item.update_target(self.player1,self.enemies,self.decoys)
            item.move()
            if self.player1.collide_widget(item):
                Clock.unschedule(self.spawn_enemy)
                Clock.unschedule(self.update)
                Clock.unschedule(self.increase_score)
    """
    def death_restart(self, player):
        if self.collide_widget(player):
            print("error")
            #main()
    """        
    def spawn_enemy(self, dt):
        if len(self.enemies) <= 8:
            x = float(random.randint(0, self.width))
            y = float(random.randint(0, self.height))
            enemy = Enemy(start_pos = (x,y),width = self.width,height = self.height)
            while distance(enemy, self.player1)< MIN_INITIAL_PLAYER_MINION_DISTANCE:
                x = float(random.randint(0, self.width))
                y = float(random.randint(0, self.height))
                enemy.pos = (x,y)

            self.enemies.append(enemy)
            self.add_widget(enemy)

    def spawn_decoy(self, location):
        x = location[0]
        y = location[1]
        decoy = Decoy(start_pos = (x,y))
        self.decoys.append(decoy)
        self.add_widget(decoy)

    def increase_score(self, dt):
        self.score += 1



    #on_touch_move vs on_touch_down
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.player1.update_target([touch.x, touch.y])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap and len(self.decoys) < MAX_DECOYS:
            self.spawn_decoy([touch.x, touch.y])


#Entry Point into app

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        game.setup()        
        return game

def main():
    GameApp().run()

main()
```

Comment: You may want to include some of the tracebacks you're getting. Is this as minimal as you can get your [mcve]?

Comment: Right, I didn't post them because they're occurring inside the Kivy modules, with thousands of lines.  Essentially, they're all coming back with "maximum recursion depth exceeded."

Comment: Well, that's an *essential* point to mention. Apparently you have either a function cycle or a function calling itself. Your traceback will tell you what that cycle involves

Comment: Good point, my mistake.  Anyway, I nearly worked out the solution.  I'll post as soon as it is perfect. :)